# How can I center this image inside of this div?

Tags: html, css, image

How can I center this image that I have in this div in a way that it won't move the 'line' div? I want the line to be touching the top of the square too.

```css
.black {
  background: black;
}

.square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 37px auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.image {
height: 60px;
width: 60px;
}

.line {
  width: 4px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="square black">  
        <img class="image" src="https://c.neh.tw/thumb/f/720/5659673474629632.jpg">
                <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="rectangle"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You've asked six other questions but haven't accepted answers for any of them. Please take the time to review the answers you've been given and if possible, accept and upvote ones that have helped you. That helps your reputation as well as that of those that have taken the time and effort to help you

Comment: okay, thank you, I'm new here, so I missed that

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to prevent it from disrupting the flow layout of your container:

you can make the container a position of relative, and the image a position of absolute, positioned off the top and left by 50%, then transform it so that the center of the image is in the center position.

You could also just make the image a background-image of the div instead of using an image element, which may be easier to manipulate.

```css
.black {
  background: black;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 37px auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.image {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.line {
  width: 4px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square black">
    <img class="image" src="https://c.neh.tw/thumb/f/720/5659673474629632.jpg">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your exact desired end goal. But, if I understand correctly, you could create a flex parent to justify the image, and then position the line absolutely within that. See -

```css
.black {
  background: black;
}

.square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 37px auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

.line {
  width: 4px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0
}
```

```html
  <div class="square black">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <img class="image" src="https://c.neh.tw/thumb/f/720/5659673474629632.jpg">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use these css for .square and .image

```
        .square {
            width: 200px;
            height: 500px;
            margin: 37px auto;
            border-radius: 2px;

            position: relative;
        }

        .image {
            height: 60px;
            width: 60px;

            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily center a image by using CSS position absolute. By making the position of square black class "absolute" and apply to properties "top: 45%;" and "left: 47%" . By applying this your problem will be definitely solve.

```css
.black {
  background: black;
}

.square {
  display: flex;
  align-item: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.image {
height: 60px;
width: 60px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="square black">  
       <img class="image" src="https://c.neh.tw/thumb/f/720/5659673474629632.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.black {
  background: black;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 47%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 37px auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.image {
height: 60px;
width: 60px;
position: absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
}

.line {
  width: 4px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="square black">  
        <img class="image" src="https://c.neh.tw/thumb/f/720/5659673474629632.jpg">
                <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="rectangle"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

```css
.black {
  background: black;
}

.square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 37px auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.image {
height: 60px;
width: 60px;
}

.line {
  width: 4px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="square black">  
        <img class="image" src="https://c.neh.tw/thumb/f/720/5659673474629632.jpg">
                <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="rectangle"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
```